# Matlab: non-monotonic interpolation

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I'm having a problem with interpolation from a non-monotonic function.

```
x=[34,35,36,37,38,39,41,42,43,44,45,46]
y=[0.33 0.166 0.25 0.33 0.5 0.58 0.66 0.66 0.5 0.58 0.8 0.66]
```

I want to be able to interpolate the X value that corresponds to a Y value of 0.25.

When plotting `(x,y)` I can see that there are two points that corresponds to a Y value of 0.25, so normal interpolation (using `interp1`) would not work.

> Error: "The grid vectors are not strictly monotonic increasing."

Is there a way to interpolate both points and then calculate their mean, I couldn't find anything that fits my problem.

Comment: where are the two values that correspond to the same `0.25` value i only see one `0.25` value in the `y` vector?

Comment: Indeed, but there is also another "hidden" value of 0.25 between the first (0.33) and second (0.166) points which I also want to interpolate.

Comment: then use a non-linear interpolation scheme as this will yield the correct  result and not a linear interpolation method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through your array and detect if your query value is passed. Then take the average value.

```
%test data
x=[34,35,36,37,38,39,41,42,43,44,45,46];
y=[0.33 0.166 0.25 0.33 0.5 0.58 0.66 0.66 0.5 0.58 0.8 0.66];

%value to query
yq = 0.25;
result = [];
for i = 1:length(y)-1
    if (y(i) <= yq && yq < y(i+1)) || (y(i) > yq && yq >= y(i+1))
        result(end+1) = interp1([y(i),y(i+1)],[x(i),x(i+1)],yq);
    end
end

xq = mean(result);
```

Comment: WOW, looks much better now, but what do you mean I have to do this by hand? Or do I misunderstand you and you mean that the code is doing a "dumb" job and go through all the points of y to check if it has passed 0.25, and average the point it passed with the next point.

Comment: iI removed that text.

Comment: I think you are god. Thanks for everyone else who helped as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can first compute the mean of the douplicates and then interpolate:

```
%test data
x=[34,35,36,37,38,39,41,42,43,44,45,46];
y=[0.33 0.166 0.25 0.33 0.5 0.58 0.66 0.66 0.5 0.58 0.8 0.66];

% sort values
[~,idx] = sort(y);
x = x(idx);
y = y(idx);

% use all values only once. Average the values
y_unique = unique(y);
x_unique = zeros(size(y_unique));
for i = 1:length(y_unique)
   x_unique(i) =  mean(x(y==y_unique(i)));
end

% test
interp1(y_unique,x_unique,0.33)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is close but I think its not exactly what I was aiming for. As you can see when plotting (y) there is another (x) point that corresponds to y=0.25. which is about 34.5. The second point is 36, which is the output I get when running the code above (with 0.25 in the last line). I want it to calculate the mean between the two points (the 34.5~ and the 36). Thanks again.

Comment: check my other answer

Answer (score 0):

You can select the unique points as:

```
% x and y are your data available
[xN, index] = unique(x);
yN = y(index);

% Now you have only unique x and y values stored in xN and yN
```

Note, that this will discard your duplicate data points.